# ODBC connection string with SSL to connect to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, c, sql-server, odbc

I'm trying to use MS native ODBC driver to connect with SQL server instance using SSL. I am trying to find some sample connection string that also passes the CA certificate for verification but i'm unable to find one.

For example, the below doc only talks about Encrypt=yes but does not talk about how to pass a ca certificate in the connection string for verification.
https://www.devart.com/odbc/sqlserver/docs/ssl.htm

Please advise.

Comment: To clarify: you're trying to pass a root CA that your end will use to verify the remote SSL certificate because that remote cert does not chain down from root?  Or are you trying to pass a client cert that the other end requires to connect?

Comment: Have you looked at connectionstrings.com? Not certain it will help, but their are a lot of connection strings there.

Comment: @SteveFriedl I'm using RDS SQL Server. So I believe it's the client certificate that I need to pass in order to connect

Comment: I couldn't find any example from connectionstrings.com as well - https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-native-client-11-0-oledb-provider/ I'm not sure what I am missing

Comment: I can't find anything about MS-SQL re: client certificates, so I wonder if this is actually what you're trying to solve. What makes you think you have to use some kind of cert in the first place? If you have one, how did you get it?

Comment: @SteveFriedl I'm trying to use sslmode=verify_full. In my experience, I have to pass the CA certificate to verify the certificate in Mysql / Posgresql. Example: psql "host=XXXX.rds.XXXX.com sslmode=require sslrootcert=rds-ssl-ca-cert.pem port=XXXX user=XXXXX dbname=XXXX"

Comment: I think you are looking for `TrustServerCertificate=false`. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-string-syntax#enabling-encryption

Comment: This sounds like it’s a server cert, and I assume the server cert is not obtained from a real root CA, instead a self signed cert. I think on Windows you have to install the cert in Windows itself, in the local cert store, and it’s not something you pass in a connection string.

Comment: @SteveFriedl Ah makes sense! I will check further from my end. Thank you!

Comment: @RMu - there are probably options that say “ignore server cert, just accept it”, but please try really hard to not to do that. This is terribly insecure, and though many of us have said “the hell with it, just connect”, it’s really really worth your time to try to make it work properly.

Comment: @SteveFriedl Makes perfect sense :)